# VB.NET Progress bar on ftp upload

Tags: vb.net, ftp, progress

Hi I am trying to add a progress bar to a FTP image upload, though I looked at many examples over the internet and I've tried numerous things but just couldn't get anything to work with my following code. I want a progress bar to track the progress of the upload then show 100% once done.

**My coding:**

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            Dim s As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
            Static r As New Random
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            For i As Integer = 1 To 8
                Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, 35)
                sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1))
            Next

            Clipboard.SetText("http://my-site.com/osdf/" + sb.ToString() + ".png")


            Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                sc.CaptureDeskTopRectangle(Me.boundsRect).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

                ''Close()
                Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
                    AddHandler wc.UploadDataCompleted, AddressOf UploadCompleted
                    wc.UploadData("ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@My-site.com/pic/uploads/" + sb.ToString() + ".png", ms.ToArray())

                End Using
                MsgBox("File Uploaded", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            End Using

        End Sub
```

How would I be able to do this using my code?

Thanks in advance, I will appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and use the WebClient event like:

```
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
    AddHandler wc.UploadDataCompleted, AddressOf wc_UploadDataCompleted
    AddHandler wc.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc_UploadProgressChanged
    wc.UploadData("ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@My-site.com/pic/uploads/" & sb.ToString() & ".png", ms.ToArray())
End Using
```

Also you need:

```
Private Sub wc_UploadDataCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.UploadDataCompletedEventArgs) 
    MsgBox("File Uploaded", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub

Private Sub wc_UploadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Net.UploadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

you will need to use "UploadDataAsync" instead of "UploadData" to be able to see the increament in the progressbar or use a BackgroundWorker with UploadData method.